# sum and groupby does not work for me using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have the following dataset:

[image]

I want to sum column `cantidad`(Amount) grouping by `nombre`(name) using pandas, so I have tried:
[image]

First row was surprised due to "Ana" is a common name, so I inspected:
[image]

Ok, so... the sum for "Ana" is 434 not 1. What is happening? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Really interesting. What return `resume = historical_names.groupby('nombre')['cantidad'].sum()` ?

Comment: @jezrael, thank you for your interest. Result is the same. You can download the dataset from [here](http://datos.gob.ar/dataset/b8418d41-8e0c-4e85-8aa8-80d51a840132/resource/811bf426-fc36-4f20-b2e1-59bdbb938153/download/nombres-1920-1924.csv)

Comment: @JohnGalt I'm going to add when I come back to my house. I have checked dtypes and I get object (nombre), np.int64 (cantidad) and np.int64 (anio)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `skipinitialspace=True` because values in column `nombre` has trailing whitespaces - so `'Ana'`, `' Ana'`, `' Ana '` ... is grouped separately:

```
historical_names = pd.read_csv('nombres-1920-1924.csv', skipinitialspace =True)
print (historical_names.head())

resume = historical_names.groupby('nombre')['cantidad'].sum()
print (resume['Ana'])
437

a = historical_names.loc[historical_names['nombre'] == 'Ana', 'cantidad']
print (a)
5        113
10340    138
18776      1
23114    183
26523      2
Name: cantidad, dtype: int64

a = historical_names.loc[historical_names['nombre'] == 'Ana', 'cantidad'].sum()
print (a)
437
```

---

```
historical_names = pd.read_csv('nombres-1920-1924.csv')
print (historical_names.head())

historical_names['nombre'] = historical_names['nombre'].str.strip()
resume = historical_names.groupby('nombre')['cantidad'].sum()
print (resume['Ana'])
437
```

---

```
historical_names = pd.read_csv('nombres-1920-1924.csv')
print (historical_names.head())

resume = historical_names.groupby('nombre')['cantidad'].sum()
print (resume['Ana'])
434

a = historical_names.loc[historical_names['nombre'] == 'Ana', 'cantidad']
print (a)
5        113
10340    138
23114    183
Name: cantidad, dtype: int64

a = historical_names.loc[historical_names['nombre'] == 'Ana', 'cantidad'].sum()
print (a)
434
```

Comment: As usual, very fast. `I came up with historical_names.nombre = historical_names.nombre.apply(lambda x: x.strip())` Would you have any insight to share pertaining to the difference in performance of this `apply` and `.str.strip()`?

Comment: @Uvar - There is difference handling `NaN`s - `str.strip()` handle `NaN`s, but `apply(lambda x: x.strip())` not.